# Killing processes with a single command?

Tags: linux, process, signals, kill, pid

When I run the command

```
ps -l -a
```

I get the list of all the processes currently running on the terminal.
[image]

I know I can kill these processes by repeatedly invoking the command "kill" like this

```
kill -9 10400
kill -9 10401
kill -9 10418
```

but is there a way to kill them all with a single command and/or without specifying pids/names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run these processes from a bash script and capture their pids by adding `& pid=$!` after the command, you can kill them one by one with their captured pids.

If you need them killed a certain time, you can setup an 'at job' or a 'cron job' and pass the pids through the environment or a file. You can also save the pids somewhere for later use with a kill script.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
      killall -9 dnsserver
      killall -9 dnns
```

This look for all process with that name and send the corresponding singal